# Does Cplex support using of ln or exponential function for a decision variable?

Tags: function, cplex, exp, ln

I am trying to write constraints using ln and exp function, yet I received an error that Cplex can't extract the expression.

```
forall (t in time)
   Gw_C["Mxr"] == 20523 + 17954 * ln(maxl(pbefore[t]));

  Ed_c ["RC"]== 0.0422* exp(0.1046* (maxl(pbefore[t])));
   
   Gw_C["RC"] == 3590* pow((maxl(pbefore[t]), 0.6776);
```

Is there any other possible way to code these constraints on cplex?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use exp and log if you rely on Constraint Programming within CPLEX:

```
using CP;

int scale=1000;

dvar int scalex in 1..10000;
dexpr float x=scalex/scale;

maximize x;

subject to
{
  exp(x)<=100;
}

execute
{
  writeln("x=",x);
}
```

works fine and gives:

```
x=4.605
```

But with Math Programming within CPLEX you cannot use exp like that.

What you can do instead if go through [linearization](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/opltipsandtricks/blob/master/interpolatewithpiecewiselinear.mod).