# Can I solve an objective function with exponential function in C-PLEX or want to linearize it?

Tags: visual-studio, optimization, cplex, exponential

This shows the objective function I have tried. It is showing like cannot extract the expression.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can take the logarithm of the objective:

```
max a*exp(b-c*x)
```

gives the same solution as:

```
max ln(a)+b-x*c
```

a,b,c are constants here, so this is now a linear objective. Of course, that means DOD is 0.3 or 0.7. So you could do this with a calculator.

Comment: And if the model is not trivial you may use Constraint Programming within CPLEX as in the example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64375290/does-cplex-support-using-of-ln-or-exponential-function-for-a-decision-variable